# How to fix error "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: " when trying to install web3 using pip

Tags: python, pip, web3py

I am trying to install web3 using pip, but it keeps running into an error.

I have seen suggestions telling me to install older versions of web3. I have already done that. After running the install command, it installs most of the components but seems to run into an error installing *cytoolz* while running *setup.py*.
(as you can see in the first line of the error message).

I am using python version 3.10.1

`pip install web3`

The error:

```
Running setup.py install for cytoolz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hvw_02uz\\cytoolz_5bf05182706b4ad08510aa829a45e3d5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hvw_02uz\\cytoolz_5bf05182706b4ad08510aa829a45e3d5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z70jeg29\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Include\cytoolz'
         cwd: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hvw_02uz\cytoolz_5bf05182706b4ad08510aa829a45e3d5\
    Complete output (49 lines):
    ALERT: Cython not installed.  Building without Cython.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\operator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\curried\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\curried
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\cpython.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\dicttoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\functoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\itertoolz.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\recipes.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\utils.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    copying cytoolz\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_compatibility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_curried_toolzlike.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dev_skip_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_dicttoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_docstrings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_embedded_sigs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_functoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_inspect_args.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_itertoolz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_none_safe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_recipes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_serialization.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_signatures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_tlz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    copying cytoolz\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\cytoolz\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'cytoolz.dicttoolz' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hvw_02uz\\cytoolz_5bf05182706b4ad08510aa829a45e3d5\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hvw_02uz\\cytoolz_5bf05182706b4ad08510aa829a45e3d5\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z70jeg29\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Include\cytoolz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I would really appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you need to download Microsoft Visual C++, which you can do here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170